# Hilbert space is sum of closed subspace and its orthogonal

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Show that $H = F + F^\perp $ where $H$ is a Hilbert space and $F$ is a closed subspace.

Could you give me an idea for how to proceed please? Thanks!

Comment: If you know about orthonormal bases, choose one for $F$ and complete it to a full orthonormal basis for $H$. The basis elements added to $F$ form an orthonormal basis for $F^{\perp}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let be $P$ the orthogonal projection
$$P:H\longrightarrow F$$
and write any $x\in H$ as
$$x=\cdots +\cdots$$